# "python manage.py makemigrations" Traceback errors after creating models.py in Django

Tags: python, django

All of these errors only started happening when i did the models.py, to the best of my knowledge i didn't write any of my code wrong. Previous "makemigrations" worked.

It seems like a lot of the Traceback errors have nothing to do with the models.py though.

*(hopefully these are easy to read, sorry)*

**The traceback error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 21, in  main()
>
> File "manage.py", line 17, in main execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File
>   "/home/alatimer/Environments/DjangoTutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django
>   /core/management/**init**.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
>   utility.execute()
>
> File
>   "/home/alatimer/Environments/DjangoTutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 377, in execute django.setup()
>
> File
>   "/home/alatimer/Environments/DjangoTutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/**init**.py",
>   line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>
> File
>   "/home/alatimer/Environments/DjangoTutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 114, in populate app_config.import_models()
>
> File
>   "/home/alatimer/Environments/DjangoTutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
>   line 211, in import_models self.models_module =
>   import_module(models_module_name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in
>   import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level)
>
> File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
>
> File "", line 971, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 955, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module
>
> File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed
>
> File "/home/alatimer/Environments/djangoproject/blog/models.py", line
>   6, in  class Post(models.Model):
>
> File "/home/alatimer/Environments/djangoproject/blog/models.py", line
>   9, in Post date_posted = models.DateTimeField(defualt=timezone.now)
>
> File
>   "/home/alatimer/Environments/DjangoTutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 1107, in **init** super().**init**(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'defualt'

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(defualt=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Typo: `defualt=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error actually says it all (last line):

> TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument **'defualt'**

So, in your models.py this line should be corrected:

```
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(defualt=timezone.now)
```

It is not defualt, it is default. You made a typo!

Comment: oh my god, im so stupid i didnt understand what Klaus D. meant in the comments. thank you so much. really helped

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is for

`date_posted = models.DateTimeField(defualt=timezone.now)`.

Try Migrate the model with out this field.If migrate then try

```
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: it can now be migrated! do you know why date_posted can't be used and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(defualt=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```